# How to do this using jQuery - document.getElementById(“formid”).elements["foo"].value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

In jQuery, what is the equivalent to document.getElementById(“formid”).elements["foo"].value ?

I am trying to get the value of the elements in a form

Thanks.

Comment: id and attr selector....

Comment: @Kinduser the name...

Comment: @epascarello Is it supposed to work then?

Comment: @Kinduser It is the name of the element. Basic DOM methods that have been around for decades.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the form HTML code? Like, which form element your trying to target.

Comment: What element type is `foo` ? input, div, select ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("formid").elements["foo"].value`

Answer (score -1):

This gets the value of the input element with name `foo` in the form with id `formid`

```
$('form[id=formid] :input[name=foo]').val();
```

Answer (score -2):

In jQuery you can get any element like this:

```
var form = $("#formId");
```

This does the same as `document.getElementById(“formid”)`.
Furthermore, you can iterate through your form and get all of it's values like:

```
var inputValues = [];
$('#formId input, #formId select').each(
    function(index){  
        var input = $(this);
        inputValues[input.attr('name')] = input.val();
    }
);
```